# Do references take up memory?

Tags: memory, struct, rust, memory-management, reference

I am currently a month or two into learning Rust and wanted to make a small program to learn it which consists of objects that have a struct containing two u8’s. My question is, whenever that struct is asked-for immutably, would cloning/copying it be more memory efficient than referencing to it since the reference would presumably take up 8 bytes on a 64-bit system, while the struct itself only uses 2 bytes?

Comment: Yes, prefer working on values when copy/move is cheap, because indirections via pointers are hard to predict for the compiler/hardware and that prevents some kind of optimisation/anticipation. The number of bytes involved is not really the main point here (except if you store many of them).

Comment: The answer is mostly "it depends." The compiler can and will inline functions/methods if it decides it would be optimal to do so, and in so doing it can often eliminate the indirection of references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A struct consisting of two u8's is basically a u16. Since u16 implements Copy, you probably want to make your struct implement Copy as well. For such small types a reference will always be larger than the type itself.

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct U16 {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
}
```